# Statements and dynamic field names

Tags: couchbase, sql++, spring-data-couchbase

I'm currently working on a query that needs to be created dynamically depending on the input. Basically in my database I store a bunch of maps of key/value pairs, and the query is a map of key/value pairs from which all key/value pairs need to match.

I've found how to use N1qlQuery.parameterized() with a statement and placeholder values using "$param", but this doesn't work for fieldnames in the Expression.x("field") clause. Problem being, while my field values will be safe from SQL injection, my field names won't if I just put the string value the user has entered in there.

How can I escape dynamically built field names in my query ?

```
    String fieldNameThatCanBeHacked = "fieldNameThatCanBeHacked";
    Statement statement = Select.select("*").from(CouchbaseConfig.BUCKET_NAME).where(Expression.x(fieldNameThatCanBeHacked).eq("$param");
```

Comment: Do you know all the possible field names in advance?

Comment: No I don't, it's totally up to the users and the future use cases.